# Как изменить местоположение информационного окна

Tags: google-maps

Как изменить местоположение информационного окна https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple - тут, в документации инф. окно открывается сверху, а мне нужно, чтоб открывалось снизу. Есть ли какие-то примеры? Спаисбо

Answer (score 0):

согласно [документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow):

> An InfoWindow can be placed on a map at a particular position or above
>   a marker, depending on what is specified in the options

окно может быть открыто в заданной позиции (координатах карты) либо **над маркером**.

Возможно есть хак с переворотами средствами css, но документированных возможностей для этих целей похоже не предусмотрено.

Comment: Нашел вот такую статью http://michaelsoriano.com/customize-google-map-info-windows-infobox/ но все равно не догоняю через какое свойство он сделал, infobox.js подключил

Comment: это отдельный плагин, он не модифицирует и настраивает старое стандартное окно, а создает свои окна

Comment: Аа, вот оно что. Спасибо.